# Error : CakePHP 1.3 Import model method

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to import model in CakePHP 1.3 version but its not working.
I have created all tables and files.All my localhost its working fine but on server its not working.Can you suggest us some solution.
I have tried it in two ways-

1. `var $uses=array('model name');`
2. `App::import('Model', 'model name');`

It give error **client location** not defined.

Thanks
Ajay

Comment: put this $this->loadModel('Your model name); in function

Comment: that is also not working bro!!

Comment: You might have missing cache/models and cache/persistent directories on your server,